# How to automatically sort the option flags in a manual?

Tags: man

I am about to create a script to edit the manual in order to have alphabetical order of the option flag in the `OPTIONS` section. Is there  a more direct and elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the manual page, it's hard to say.  But supposing that your manual is formatted consistently, e.g.,

```
.TP 5
.B \-a
description of \fB\-a\fP option
.TP 5
.B \-b
description of \fB\-b\fP option
```

and so forth, you *could* write a Perl script to pick up the options with the following paragraphs and write a manual page with the options sorted.  (bash and awk appear underpowered for this task, at least not useful for [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html), for instance).

If your manual page markup is inconsistent, e.g., using markup for options that can be easily mistaken for other descriptive matter, that would complicate the script.  But realistically, once it is sorted, you would not revisit that task often, and (if you have enough manual pages to justify the time spent on a script), the script would be reusable.

Alternatively, you could store all of the options in files and sort that list (by option name).  That's certainly less elegant, and doesn't help much with reusability.

Someone might already have a reusable script; getting consistent input helps a lot though.